# WebPack custom font loading resulted OTS PARSING ERROR: invalid sfntVersion:

Tags: webpack, fonts

I am using webpacker and developing simple static html website but custom font loading causes OTS PARSING ERROR: invalid sfntVersion

This is the style I set in font.css file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'themify';
    src:url('../fonts/themify.woff') format('woff');
    src:url('../fonts/themify.eot?#iefix-fvbane') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/themify.woff?-fvbane') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/themify.ttf?-fvbane') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/themify.svg?-fvbane#themify') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This is the error I got.
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/c5d65aebe9531b4bbcb6.ttf?-fvbane
localhost/:1 OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1702391919

When I type url `http://localhost:8080/c5d65aebe9531b4bbcb6.ttf?-fvbane` directly, it downloads font in browser. So I believe file is pointed correctly.

But not sure what causes this issue.

Weird thing is it works well in safari browser.

Just in chrome and firefox.

Any help and suggestions should be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29):

This issue occurs when trying to use custom loaders for fonts with webpack 5^. Webpack has introduced a new asset module feature that aims to replace custom loaders for fonts, images, etc.

You can solve issue issue by using

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.woff2?$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
    dependency: { not: ['url'] },
  }, 
]
```

instead of

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.woff2?$/i,
    loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
      name(file) {
        return "[hash].[ext]";
      },
    },
  }, 
]
```

Comment: Thank you sar! You saved my time! God bless you!

Comment: This is a correct answer!

Answer (score 6):

Are you using the `loaders` module? It has been deprecated, I had the same issue when using the `file-loader` module. Migrated to use [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) and that fixed the same issue.