# getting 404 GET request when using @font-face in SCSS using webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I Don't understand what's wrong with this code the fonts in the front-end is not loading up

```
@font-face {
    font-family: $font-suisse-bp;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('../../fonts/SuisseIntl-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../../fonts/SuisseIntl-Light.woff') format('woff');
}
```

[I checked the path it's correct! But it show the error in the Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZoNb.png)

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack';

import TerserPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin';
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';
import ImageMinimizerPlugin from 'image-minimizer-webpack-plugin';
import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from 'clean-webpack-plugin';

const IS_DEVELOPMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev'
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

const dirApp = path.join(__dirname, 'app')
const dirShared = path.join(__dirname, 'shared')
const dirStyles = path.join(__dirname, 'styles')
const dirNode = 'node_modules'

export default {
    entry: [
        path.join(dirApp, 'index.js'),
        path.join(dirStyles, 'index.scss')
    ],

    resolve: {
        modules: [
            dirApp,
            dirShared,
            dirStyles,
            dirNode
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            IS_DEVELOPMENT: JSON.stringify(IS_DEVELOPMENT)
        }),

        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: './shared',
                    to: '',
                    noErrorOnMissing: true
                }
            ]
        }),

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css'
        }),

        new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
            minimizer: {
                implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminMinify,
                options: {
                    plugins: [
                      ["gifsicle", { interlaced: true }],
                      ["jpegtran", { progressive: true }],
                      ["optipng", { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
                    ],
                }
            },
        }),

        new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },

            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            publicPath: ''
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                test: /\.(jge?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|fnt|webp)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    // limit: 100000,
                    name (file) {
                        return '[hash].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            },

            {
                test: /\.(jge?g|png|gif|svg|webp)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: ImageMinimizerPlugin.loader,
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },

            {
                test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
                loader: 'glslify-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },

    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
    }
}
```

This is my webpack.config file

I tried url-loader but doesn't seem to work.

Expecting it to load the font in front-end

[0] GET /e44611ae26a81ff67630.woff2 404 1.907 ms - 165
[0] GET /0f8be412ab2bd6c4db5c.woff 404 1.273 ms - 164

I get this on the Terminal with 404

Comment: OTS parsing errors usually indicate, your **font file got corrupted**. Probably related to [this webpacks issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468150/webpack-custom-font-loading-resulted-ots-parsing-error-invalid-sfntversion)