# Failed to decode downloaded font/downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer with Gidole font using sass

Tags: css, sass, fonts

I have a react proyect that is using sass and have the following structure:

```
src
-assets
--fonts
---GidolinyaRegular.otf
---Fonts.scss
---Gidolinya-Regular.ttf
---Gidolinya-Regular.woff
---Gidolinya-Regular.woff2
---Gidolinya-Regular.svg
-components
--Navbar.scss
```

Code in Fonts.scss is:

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Gidolinya';
    src: url('Gidolinya-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('Gidolinya-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Gidolinya-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('Gidolinya-Regular.svg#Gidolinya-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

And in Navbar.scss is:

```
@import '../assets/fonts/Fonts';

.navbar{
    font-family: 'Gidolinya', sans-serif;
}
```

I'm having the trouble that always browser is using, in this case, sans serif and showing the following error: **Failed to decode downloaded font** on Edge or **downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer** on Firefox for Gidole, that font is available on (https://github.com/larsenwork/Gidole)

I tried other solutions that people bring here to similar problems, Like rename the way the font is imported (adding "-webfont"), change the path in url to an absolute path, change .otf to .ttf or .woff but none of them worked and I'm still having the trouble.
Changing the way it is imported makes the error message disapear but still didn't use the font

Comment: If you see an encoding error in your console it means your font file was corrupted during an upload or more likely a packaging process. Bundlers like webpack are notoriously dump trying to copy binary font files as text files. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468150/webpack-custom-font-loading-resulted-ots-parsing-error-invalid-sfntversion). BTW you can sefely remove the `svg` font files - not supported by firefox or chromium ... and not needed by webkit

Comment: Not the same error as that post but it worked! Thank you so much!