# The font is displayed on Iphone 11, but is not used on Iphone 14. How is that possible?

Tags: html, css, iphone, fonts

I connect font from files using font-face.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Mak";
    src: url('../fonts/MAK.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/MAK.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/MAK-bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/MAK-bold.woff') format('woff'),
  }
```

I tried to upload it on guithub and other hosting services, but it didn`t help

Comment: Use the browser's devtools (console or network) to see if the fonts are even getting loaded. Perform your tests on a computer or device that you can open the devtools on. Once you have confirmed the fonts are loading, then work on tweaking functionality for other devices.

Comment: On all other devices it works. The desktop version works as well. I open my website on Iphone 11 and I can see the fonts, but when I open it from Iphone 14 - the fonts are not applied for some reason

Comment: Interesting. See here where the same/similar issue is discussed https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671608  .... Further down on the page is mentioned `Oh, one more thing -- I discovered a work-around. If I preload the font file, it works...`

Comment: I should preload it like this?
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/MAK.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>

Comment: I'm not familiar with it. You might want to search "best practices for preloading web fonts" to see what the current literature is on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

[Preloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330825/preloading-font-face-fonts#46830425) the font files can certainly improve loading times as commented.

However, always **double-check your `@font-face` rule.**
Currently, it has some syntax errors.

1. replace the final comma with a semicolon – the trailing comma actually invalidates the `url` property.
2. you need 2 font-face rules for regular and the bold font-weight. Otherwise, the browser will render bold text in "faux bold" – the same applies to italic styles.

We can safely remove the deprecated `.eot` (used by the discontinued Internet Explorers) – same applies to the also deprecated `.svg` font file format.

The final CSS `@font-face` rule should look something like this.

```css
/* Regular – font-weight: normal/400 */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mak";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/MAK.woff") format("woff");
}

/* Italic – font-weight: normal/400; font-style:italic – if available */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mak";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url("../fonts/MAK-italic.woff") format("woff");
}

/* Bold – font-weight: bold/700*/
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mak";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/MAK-bold.woff") format("woff");
}

/* Bold italic – font-weight: bold/700; font-style:italic – if available*/
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mak";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url("../fonts/MAK-bold-italic.woff") format("woff");
}
```

Some browsers may be more forgiving - allowing minor syntax errors.
Usually, even **minor mistakes disable the `@font-face` rules** completely.

#### Common pitfalls

##### 1. Wrong font file paths/URLs:

*»font renders on desktop but not on mobile device«*

Double check your paths and **check your page via DevTools**.
If you can't see an entry in the network tab (filtered by fonts)
– you probably see this font rendered on desktop but not on mobile just because  you've installed it locally  for design/prototyping/mockup purposes.

##### 2. Invalid `@font-face` rules

As mentioned before most browser are quite unforgiving. Here are some common mistakes:

**2.1. Wrong format identifier**
In fact most modern browsers don't necessarily need these so might ditch them completely ... with regards to backwards compatibility still a good idea to include them.

*Not working*

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mak";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url("../fonts/MAK-bold-italic.ttf") format("ttf");
}
```

The correct identifier would be `format("truetype")`

*Correct*

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mak";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url("../fonts/MAK-bold-italic.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Similarly the correct identifier for ".otf" files would be `format("opentype")`
Fortunately both use-cases are quite irrelevant as we should prefer the perfectly supported newer `.woff2` or `.woff` formats anyway as they provide a more advanced file compression.

**2.2. Errors in `src` property**
If you modify the `src` property's url array make sure you close this property value correctly

*Not Correct – trailing comma at the end of the property*

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mak";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url("../fonts/MAK-bold-italic.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("../fonts/MAK-bold-italic.woff") format("woff"),
}
```

*Correct – replace trailing comma with semicolon*

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mak";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url("../fonts/MAK-bold-italic.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("../fonts/MAK-bold-italic.woff") format("woff");
}
```

##### 3. Corrupted font-files

Fortunately, browser devTools return an error like like `OTS parsing error`. Possible reasons:

1. if you're using **bundlers like webpack** your font file might have been copied in an inappropriate transfer mode. See also this SO post ["WebPack custom font loading resulted OTS PARSING ERROR: invalid sfntVersion:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468150/webpack-custom-font-loading-resulted-ots-parsing-error-invalid-sfntversion).
2. You may experience similar issues when working with **CMS font uploads** – in this case file a bug report. A server side script may transfer or convert the font file resulting in an invalid font file.
3. The font might be of **questionable quality** – some free fonts may not meat the standards required by browsers to parse a font (e.g missing important data records)

You can also check if your font-family is available in the `woff2` – since this format it compact it also speeds up the font loading.