# How to use cursive letters with Pacifico font?

Tags: html, css, fonts, truetype, google-fonts

The [Pacifico](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Pacifico/glyphs) font supports many scripts like:
Latin Lowercase, Latin Uppercase, Cyrillic Lowercase.. and each one displays a specific cursive glyph.

If I use the font with Cyrillic text, how can I specifically make use of the cursive glyph showed in the image and not just the capitalized `д` for example, and also not explicitly using italics or slanted letters.

[image]

I have downloaded the Pacifico font into `static/fonts/` and then tried with:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
 @font-face {
     font-family: 'Pacifico'; 
     src:
     local('Pacifico Regular'),
      url('/static/fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf format("truetype")');
 }
 .pacifico-font {
     font-size: 5em ;
     font-family:'Pacifico';
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span class="pacifico-font">д</span>
</body>
</html>
```

But it is still swowing `д`.

Comment: Hi. Could you try with `url('/static/fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');`?

Comment: @Philippe tried it but same as before, font loads ok but can't choose the cursive glyph.

Comment: How are you sur that the font is well loaded? Il tried with the alternate method `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`  in the `head` section and then the cursive glyph appears :)

Comment: @Philippe  Thanks! You are right, worked with your method, need to figure out why it doesn't worked self hosted

Comment: You're welcome, good news. Btw, I have posted this answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange behavior, this alternative works fine :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    .pacifico-font {
      font-size: 5em;
      font-family: 'Pacifico';
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <span class="pacifico-font">д</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Maybe a problem with the downloaded font or with the declarations syntax, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Your `@font-face` syntax has an error:
you must not include the format identifier in the `url` property

```
url('/static/fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf format("truetype")');
```

should be

```
url('/static/fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf') format("truetype");
```

(Doesn't matter if you're using double or single quotes)

### `@font-face` syntax is unforgiving

Even minor typos invalidate the whole rule.

```css
body{
  font-size: 5em ;
}

/* incorrect syntax */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v22/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6D6MmTpA.woff2 format("woff2")');
}

/* correct syntax */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico-correct';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v22/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6D6MmTpA.woff2') format("woff2");
}


 .pacifico-font {
     font-family:'Pacifico';
 }

 .pacifico-font-correct {
     font-family:'Pacifico-correct';
 }
```

```html
<p class="pacifico-font">д</p>
<p class="pacifico-font-correct">д</p>
```

### Local font sources

Besides, better avoid `local()` font rules trying to fetch a locally installed font – they tend to fail or may be blocked completely due to browser security setting.

### Fonts loaded – relative paths correct?

If you're uncertain: check the browsers's dev tools (network tab/fonts).

If you can't see an entry for the locally hosted font file – there is something wrong with your paths.

Keep in mind the path must be relative to the final output directory of your CSS file (in case ure using a preprocessor like Sass/Scss this can sometimes be confusing).

### Preferred font formats

You should also prefer `woff2` files due to their improved file compression.
When downloading the font as .ttf via  google font UI you get a quite large font file – due to the truetype format but also due to the lack of subsets.
If your page/app provides something like a language switch you may not need to load the full-range glyph support for all languages at once. Instead you may load language dependent subsets on demand (e.g switching between English and Russian)

### OTS parsing errors

These error logs you can see in your dev tool console indicate, the font file itself was corrupted at some point. Maybe during a upload process or caused by sub-optimal web-bundler settings (e.g copying font-files not as binary files) See  ["WebPack custom font loading resulted OTS PARSING ERROR: invalid sfntVersion:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468150/webpack-custom-font-loading-resulted-ots-parsing-error-invalid-sfntversion).

There are also great helper like ["google webfont helper"](https://gwfh.mranftl.com/fonts) to retrieve a "font-kit".
Alternatively, you may code your own helper (See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/JjVYBmb))